# How to overwrite using stdio.h?

Tags: c, stdio

I wanted to overwrite an existing file, which should be simple:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *f;
    unsigned char ba;
    int i;

    f = fopen("junk", "wb");
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        fputc(i, f);
    fclose(f);
    f = fopen("junk", "ab");
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);

    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        printf("Position before: %ld\n", ftell(f));
        fputc(99, f);
        printf("Position after: %ld\n", ftell(f));
    }

    fclose(f);
    f = fopen("junk", "rb");

    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) { 
        ba = fgetc(f);
        printf("%d ", ba); 
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

The result is:

```
Position before: 0
Position after: 11
Position before: 11
Position after: 12
Position before: 12
Position after: 13
Position before: 13
Position after: 14
Position before: 14
Position after: 15
Position before: 15
Position after: 16
Position before: 16
Position after: 17
Position before: 17
Position after: 18
Position before: 18
Position after: 19
Position before: 19
Position after: 20
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

The idea is to write a file in write mode, then reopen in write/append mode, overwrite the first 5 bytes, then open in read mode and read the contents of the 10 bytes out. The result should have been:

```
99 99 99 99 99 6 7 8 9 10
```

As you see from the trace, instead `<stdio.h>` ignores the `fseek()` to zero and appends at the end in any case. Obviously this is distilled from a more complex program, but this behavior makes no sense to me.

Comment: You can only write to the *end* of a file opened for **append**, regardless of the seeking. That's what it is for. Open in mode `"rb+"` to overwrite.

Comment: Sure, but that behavior is undocumented. Is the effect that after opening in mode a that all further seeks to the file are ignored? The description says "Open for reading and appending (writing at end of file). The file is created if it does not exist.  Output is always appended to the end of the file." so I would guess so. (since it says "always").

Comment: It absolutely *is* documented. MSVC says in [fopen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen?view=msvc-170) *When a file is opened by using the `"a"` access type or the `"a+"` access type, all write operations occur at the end of the file. The file pointer can be repositioned by using `fseek` or `rewind`, but is always moved back to the end of the file before any write operation is performed. Therefore, existing data can't be overwritten.*

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen "On the append file access modes, data is written to the end of the file regardless of the current position of the file position indicator."

Comment: Yes, I agree that is more explicit than the Linux documentation.

Comment: Your quote is clear though: *appending (writing at end of file) ... Output is always appended to the end of the file.* It says so twice.

Comment: *"Open for appending (writing at end of file).  The file is
              created if it does not exist.  The stream is positioned at
              the end of the file."* ---> The Linux man page is clear enough.

Comment: Aside: `unsigned char ba;` should be `int ba;`, again the documentation shows `int fgetc(FILE *stream);`.

Comment: @Haris no, *trat* place is not clear enough. There is another one on the same page. "Opening a file in append mode (a as the first character of mode) causes all subsequent write operations to this stream to occur at end-of-file".

Comment: The statement ba = fgetc(f) holds because the int is promoted, or rather reduced to unsigned char. It only matters if you are checking EOF, since that is -1, which the code is not.

Comment: Obviously my opinion, but "all further seeks to the file will be ignored", deserves mention in both the doc on fopen() and fseek().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only write to the end of a file opened for append, regardless of the seeking. That's what it is for. Open in mode "rb+" to overwrite. [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75348028/how-to-overwrite-using-stdio-h#comment132952894_75348028)

Given the requirement "reopen in write/append mode", I see opening with `"rb+"` [open binary file for update (reading and writing)] still meeting that goal.

> Sure, but that [behavior is undocumented.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75348028/how-to-overwrite-using-stdio-h#comment132953036_75348028)

The behavior is well documented in the C spec.

> Opening a file with append mode (’a’ as the first character in the mode argument) causes all subsequent writes to the file to be forced to the then current end-of-file, regardless of intervening calls to the fseek function. ... C17dr § 7.21.5.3 6

Other derived documentation may or may not be so informative.  When in doubt about the C language or standard library, check the language specification.

Answer (score 2):

The file is open for appending with `"ab"`: any output is performed at the end of the file.  As you can see from the output, the first `fputc()` performs an implied `fseek(SEEK_END, 0L, f)`.

If you opened it for `"ab+"` you could seek anywhere into the file and read from there but all output would still first seek to the end of the file.

If you mean to overwrite a part of the file and leave the rest intact, you should open it with `"rb+"`.

Also note that the last call to `fopen`: `fopen("junk", "rb");` does not store the stream pointer to `f`. Further reading from `f`, that was closed before, works by coincidence, the behavior is actually undefined.

Comment: I solved it in my code by rb+ (as described). I was/am of the school that, if possible, a file should be clearly opened in either read or write mode and not read/write. Why? Because the OS can allow multiple writers if they are read only. So the "good citizen" method for mutitasking OSes would be described as "read mostly and make your updates short and quick, then revert back to read. Note that for a database file, this virtually screams append, as in adding records to the end of a file, but database programs need to do updates on previous records as well. I did get around it (cont).

Comment: I use "rb+" to do updates, then "r" mode, and close and open the file each time. This opens up classic multi-reader/writer issues with files, but that is why god make lock files.

Comment: I didn't follow the last point. The doc says fopen("junk", "rb") resets the file location to 0. The sequence would be write a bit, fclose() a named file which flushes any buffered write, then reopen in read mode at location 0. The analysis of these simple calls is sometimes complex, but that is why you and I get the big bucks.

Comment: Above should say "OS can allow multiple readers". Beyond the edit limit.

Comment: @ScottFranco: simply the last call `fopen("junk", "rb");` should be `f = fopen("junk", "rb");`

Comment: Ah OIC brain fail :-)

Comment: @ScottFranco: *I was/am of the school that, if possible, a file should be clearly opened in either read or write mode and not read/write*: I fully agree, yet `rb+` is necessary because `wb` would truncate the file.  There is no `fopen` mode string to open for `writing` only without either truncation or append semantics.

Comment: What would have been wrong with "a" mode if it were positionable? This strikes me as more reasonable than ignoring seeks. Ie., it is a write mode, does not clear the file, defaults to the end of the file (reasonable), but could be used to update anywhere in the file IF seek worked.

Comment: @ScottFranco: the semantics of the mode strings were chosen close to 50 years ago, they cannot be changed as it would break countless programs relying explicitly or implicitly on these semantics.

Comment: Yes and no. I wrote a clib for embedded use that does not do that, and have used in many places with existing programs. Its one of the issues with Posix, that is, a standard designed around existing code vs. a standard that code is designed to. But of course I grant your point! I guess I like to complain :-)